# Setting the Recordset property of an Access form

Tags: vba, ms-access

Getting Run-time error '438', Object doesn't support this property or method.

Edit: The Full code, the DB_CONNECTION is public and set in a different module and it is working.

```
Function subFormUpdate()
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset


With rs
.ActiveConnection = DB_CONNECTION
.Open "SELECT * FROM napr"
End With

If rs.EOF Then

DB_CONNECTION.Execute "CREATE TABLE napr(" _
                & " num int(2) not null unique, " _
                & "name varchar(255) null );"
End If

With Forms!Main!FormDirections!TableDirSubForm.Form
.Recordset = rs
.Requery
End With

End Function
```

Getting it on ".Recordset = rs", where 'rs' is an ADODB Recordset.

The form is just a Blank subform. Do I have to do anything else in order to view the recordset on the form?

Comment: that error suggests that there is no such method `.Recordset` for your object `.Form` -- it has nothing to do with a missing reference.

Comment: Well, ok but what can I do i that case? Because there is supposed to be such method and it is even detected by the intellisense.

Comment: Try `Set .Recordset = rs`

Comment: Run-time error 7965, The object you entered is not a valid Recordset property, when I do it with 'Set .Recordset = rs'

Comment: Can you give us a little more context?

Comment: Not sure, but can you open a recordset, then create the table and then set the forms recordset to the recordset? Try also to make the rs-variable global.

Comment: The whole Idea is to show that SELECT statement in a subform, which is already created and set at some position on the parent form. Also the sub form on which I am trying to view the results is just a blank form. Do i need to set it somehow before being able to do that. Also I didnt really get what you mean with "then create the table"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of recordset returneds by Form.Recordset depends on what kind of file you're using and you don't have any control over it. If you're using a native Access file, the recordset will be DAO. If you're using ADP, the recordset will be ADO. ADP is deprecated in version 2013, but that's why the help says the Recordset property can be either type.

Your likely problem (once you properly include the Set keyword) is that you're trying to assign an ADODB.Recordset object to a DAO.Recordset2 object. You could use the TypeName function at a breakpoint to confirm it. Change your recordset to DAO and it will work.

Comment: So I either have to switch to DAO recordset or move my project from MDB to ADP i guess. As I read ADP is good to use as a front end of SQL server and this is what I am trying to do but HOW can I transfer my MDB Front end (the forms, their logic, etc.) to ADP? Or is the usage of DAO going to change anything?

Comment: ADP was deprecated in 2013, so I wouldn't invest anything into it. There's no downside, in my mind, to using DAO. I often use both in the same project.